# How to find a "Copy link to highlight" menu in Vivaldi?

Tags: google-chrome, url, highlighting, sharing, vivaldi

Chromium [introduced](https://www.theverge.com/2021/4/17/22389519/google-feature-chrome-90-highlighted-links) a feature to create a user urls anchored to arbitrary text in page that user highlighted.

In chromium it is available in right mouse button menu. But I cannot see it in Vivaldi (version 5.0.2497.28).

How to make it available in Vivaldi?

Comment: That is a Chrome feature not a Chromium feature.

Comment: But I have it in Chromium. I am on Arch Linux, chromium 96.0.4664.93

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Vivaldi not implemented this feature.

I have found a workaround. Install [Link to Text Fragment](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-to-text-fragment/pbcodcjpfjdpcineamnnmbkkmkdpajjg) extension. Now you will get the same functionality in Vivaldi.